# Postgresql column not exists when trying to insert

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, string-constant

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS workspace;

CREATE TABLE "workspace" (
            "wk_space" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
            "token" TEXT,
            PRIMARY KEY("wk_space", "token")
        );
        
INSERT INTO "workspace" ("wk_space", "token") VALUES ("team1", "upreawnysoafa22sva") ON CONFLICT (wk_space, token) DO NOTHING;

SELECT * FROM workspace;
```

This will give an error saying `column "team1" does not exist`. If I replace the values `("team1", "upreawnysoafa22sva")` to numbers like `(11, 22)`, it works fine. I don't know what's going wrong.

Comment: use single quotes for column names. Double quotes are used for DB objects (tables, etc.). INSERT INTO "workspace" ("wk_space", "token") VALUES ('team1', 'upreawnysoafa22sva')

Comment: @Jesusbrother: I think you meant "*use single quotes for column **values***"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yup, thanks to correcting me (: